# How to Add TaskInstanceGroup to AWS EMR for autoscaling using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, autoscaling

I want to add a auto scaling group for Task Nodes and unable to get it to work with cloudformation.

Same thing works fine for CoreInstanceGroup like below.

```
Instances:
        CoreInstanceGroup:
          InstanceCount: 1
          InstanceType: !Ref CoreInstanceType
          Market: ON_DEMAND
          Name: Core Instance
          AutoScalingPolicy:
            Constraints:
              MinCapacity: !Ref CoreMinCapacity
              MaxCapacity: !Ref CoreMaxCapacity
```

When i replace CoreInstanceGroup with TaskInstanceGroup, the linter gives a warning and on running the script fails with error Property Not found.

Came across a Terraform script which refers to the TaskInstanceGroup. Anyone has had a way to figure this out ?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task Instance group is not part of [AWS::EMR::Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticmapreduce-cluster-jobflowinstancesconfig.html). Thats why you are getting the error.
You have attach TaskInstanceGroup as different resource.
Which is [AWS::EMR::InstanceGroupConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-instancegroupconfig.html).

---

`JobFlowId: !Ref myEMRCluster` this will determine in which cluster it is going to attach the resource. `myEMRCluster` is the resource name of EMR.
You can attach multiple TaskInstanceGroup with different autoscaling policy.
Also you can have different CloudFormation script for your task group. In that case you have to pass cluster id like `JobFlowId: 'j-ABCD123456789'`.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  myEMRCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::EMR::Cluster'
    Properties: <... Your existing config ...>
  TaskInstanceGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EMR::InstanceGroupConfig'
    Properties:
      InstanceRole: TASK
      InstanceCount: 0
      InstanceType: 'r5.8xlarge'
      Market: SPOT
      BidPrice: '1.110'
      Name: cfnTask
      JobFlowId: !Ref myEMRCluster
      AutoScalingPolicy:
        Constraints:
          MinCapacity: 0
          MaxCapacity: 40
        Rules:
          - Name: container-pending-ratio-scale-out
            Description: >-
              Replicates the default scale-out rule in the console for YARN
              memory.
            Action:
              SimpleScalingPolicyConfiguration:
                AdjustmentType: CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY
                ScalingAdjustment: 10
                CoolDown: 300
            Trigger:
              CloudWatchAlarmDefinition:
                ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
                EvaluationPeriods: 2
                MetricName: ContainerPendingRatio
                Namespace: AWS/ElasticMapReduce
                Period: 300
                Threshold: 2
                Statistic: AVERAGE
                Unit: COUNT
                Dimensions:
                  - Key: JobFlowId
                    Value: '${emr.clusterId}'
          - Name: idle-scale-in
            Description: Replicates the default scale-in rule in the console for idle.
            Action:
              SimpleScalingPolicyConfiguration:
                AdjustmentType: CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY
                ScalingAdjustment: -40
                CoolDown: 300
            Trigger:
              CloudWatchAlarmDefinition:
                ComparisonOperator: LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL
                EvaluationPeriods: 2
                MetricName: ContainerAllocated
                Namespace: AWS/ElasticMapReduce
                Period: 300
                Threshold: 0
                Statistic: AVERAGE
                Unit: COUNT
                Dimensions:
                  - Key: JobFlowId
                    Value: '${emr.clusterId}'
  myEMRStep:
    Type: 'AWS::EMR::Step'
    Properties: <... If you have any ...>
```

Hope this helps.